# Using an ARM template function leads to a deserialization error

Tags: json, azure

I'm publishing an ARM template to create an alert and am utilizing the [subscription()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-scope#subscription) template function to gather the user's subscription, which is to be used in the 'scopes' property

```
"scopes": "[subscription().id]",
```

This, however, is leading to a deserialization error `` "The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Error converting value \"/subscriptions/abcdef-abcd-abcd-1234-abcdasdj12\" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] ``

The subscription id is properly gathered, however it does not convert to type `` 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] ``.

Answer (score 0):

Changing

`"scopes": "[subscription().id]",`

to

```
        "Scopes": [
            "[subscription().id]"
        ],
```

fixed it